# How Assign To User In Many To Many Relationship at laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, foreign-keys, many-to-many, relationship

I have 3 table 
**User Table :**

```
| id | name | email          | password |
|----|------|----------------|----------|
| 1  | jack | jack@gmail.com | 123456   |
```

**Sites Table :**

```
| id | name   | url        |
|----|--------|------------|
| 1  | google | google.com |
```

I want to do this work On Laravel:
when a user Adds A site , Atomatically adds that site to that user on site_user table
For example when i add site google with url google.com , adds a row on site_user table with this contents :
**site_user Table :**

```
| id | user_id | site_id |
|----|---------|---------|
| 1  | 1       | 1       |
```

that is says site_id 1 belongs to user_id 1 . how can i do this?

I have two model site and user :
**On Site Model:**

```
public function users(){
        return $this->belongsToMany(User::class,'site_user','site_id','user_id'); 
    }
```

**On User Model:**

```
public function sites(){
        return $this->belongsToMany(Site::class,'site_user','user_id','site_id');  
    }
```

And in Controller i don't know how can i do this work! please help me@

Comment: So far, what's your code in the controller?

Comment: I want this@ this is my code in controller : ```public function store(Request $request)
    { Site::create($request-all());}```

Comment: above code only create data on 2nd table , Sites Table . i want to create data automatically after this code on site_user Table

Answer (score 0):

https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many
In your controllers:

```php
$user = Auth::user();
$sites = $user->sites()->get(); // This will get the sites belongs to user
```

```php
$site = Site::first();
$users = $site->users()->get(); // This will get the users belongs to site
```

```php
$user = Auth::user();
$site = Site::create($request->all());
$user->sites()->attach($site->id);  // This will build the relationship with site and user
```

```php
$user = Auth::user();
$site_ids = [1,2,3];
$user->sites()->sync($site_ids);  // This will create the not exist relationship in $site_ids, and delete the exist relationship not in $site_ids;
```

Comment: Thanks but i don't know how can i use your codes! can you explain more that how can i do this work in sitesController.php ?

Comment: I think you need to create your site firstly, and then get the site_id you created,and find the user to build the relationship by attach like the third part.